# Return a substring from a text that exists in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

> **Edited**
>
> this is the edited question after based on clarifications from the community on the topic, see the changes to see the origional
>   question

I am working with `python` and `numpy`, I have an address like below:

```
address = '4835 e. cactus rd suite 445 nightingale drive az 85254 usa'
```

and a `Data Frame` named `roads_dataframe` like below:

```
ID         road_match_array        road_width
b12        cactus rd               132
dk24       rosemont blvd           93
A93        research drive          843
h3         colorado blvd           328
```

What I want to do is, get the substring in `address` that exists in the `road_match_array` column of the `roads_dataframe`. In other words I want to get the part of the address string that exists in the `roads_match_array`.

The condition is there can be many matches in the road_match_array that might be a part of the address, some might be duplicate while some would be unique. In either cases, both the duplicate ones and the unique one's should be a part of the output dataframe.

I have a total of 1 million roads out of which I want to identify the ones that are present in a given address string. there can be no roads, 1 road or maybe 2 roads, completely depends on the input address

Comment: any reason you are using a `numpy` array for this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga since it gets really out of hand when I try to use for loops here due to the complexity (big O) and the performance is really bad, since the `road_match_array` can have upto 1 million records while the `address` can be upto 15 words long.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt there are any speed benefits here. Your `numpy.ndarray` will require an `object` dtype, which is pretty much a less useful python `list`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga would `pandas` be able to handle it in a better manner?

Comment: What data type does your array hold? I.e. what does `road_match_array.dtype` return?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov it returns a `dtype('<U14')`

Comment: I think there's really no cutting corners in terms of optimizing a search in your example, though you could parallelize the search across your cores if you want to speed up the search across the 1 million records against your address. Also, how are you loading the 1 million records into your array? Is this loaded from a database?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr it's from a set of csv's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with going for the ngram approach using `nltk`. below is the code:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk import word_tokenize


all_grams = sorted([' '.join(t) for i in range(1, 6) for t in ngrams(word_tokenize(address), i)], key=len)
intersections = roads_dataframe.loc[roads_dataframe['road_match_array'].isin(all_grams)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do:

```
road = [i for i in road_match_array if i in address]

# road = ['cactus rd']
```

For a large operation, consider using `pandas` module.  [Taken from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548437/smarter-way-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-in-a-list-python/48550505#48550505), assuming you have a `DataFrame` object with a column named `Address` in it:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df['address'], df['address'].str.extract('(?P<road>{})'.format("|".join(road_match_array)), expand=True)], axis=1)
```

Should return a similar `DataFrame` below:

```
                                            Address             road
0  4835 e. cactus rd suite 445 nightingale drive ...       cactus rd
1  4835 e. research drive suite 445 nightingale d...  research drive
```

This solution assumes you only have up to 1 match from `road_match_array` for any row.

Comment: would it be advisable if there were 1 million records to iterate over for 15 words in an address? There must be a better way than this

Comment: For that number of operations, `pandas` would be a more viable candidate.  I'm assuming you have a `DataFrame` object with addresses in a column? If so you can try a `str.extract()` and it should work.  I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: there might be some confusion, the address is a plain simple string, it's not a part of the dataframe, the `roads_dataframe` is a data frame that has the column named `roads_to_match`. And I want to get the part of the `address string` that exists in the `roads_to_match`. Also,   I'll have many matches in the road_match_array that might be a part of the address, some might be duplicate while some would be unique. In either cases, I require both the duplicate ones and the unique one's in the output dataframe if it's possible

Comment: I would recommend to please update your original question with a sample object and what is the expected output (e.g. if you are looking for a DataFrame) for clarity.  If I'm understanding correctly, there are 1 million roads that you want to match against a single 15 word length address.

Comment: I'll edit the question. But for the later part, I have a total of 1 million roads out of which I want to identify the ones that are present in a given address string. there can be no roads, 1 road or maybe 2 roads, completely depends on the input address

Answer (score 0):

This is probably going to be a rather drawn out answer but here is how I would approach the problem.

Since you're loading your substrings from a CSV, it might be worthwhile to stream the records from your CSV files.

In addition, you can pass your search job with either Python's multithreading library or [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/). I have a [blog post](https://blog.pursuitofzen.com/python-parallelism-with-multithreading-and-dask/) about Python parallelism.

My sample csv of "substrings" to search:

```
road one
former road
night road
president street
road one
former road
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
night road
president street
road one
former road
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
night road
president street
road one
former road
night road
president street
road one
former road
night road
president street
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
road one
former road
night road
president street
road one
former road
night road
president street
one lane
highway drive
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
sunset blvd
road one
former road
night road
president street
road one
former road
night road
president street
road one
former road
night road
president street
one lane
highway drive
sunset blvd
```

Actual code:

```
import csv
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

my_address = "1234 sunset blvd hollywood highway drive, california 91210"


def search_address(my_csv_row):
    if my_csv_row[0] in my_address:  # the 0th index is the column in question
        return my_csv_row[0]


pool = Pool()
with open('sample.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    results = pool.map(search_address, reader)
pool.close()
pool.join()

print([x for x in results if x])
```

Result:

```
['highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd', 'sunset blvd', 'highway drive', 'sunset blvd']
```

The benefit of this approach is:

1. You don't have to load all 1 million records into memory. You are just streaming row by row for your Python threads to evaluate.
2. You are parallelizing your search across threads so you cut down on the search time.